# How to make a POST request for Stripe Connect access token in Node?

Tags: node.js, heroku, stripe-payments

hello im at this point on the documentation 
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts#token-request

So my issue is i dont know how to make a Post request in node,

ive tried many examples but cant get it. can someone guide me in the right direction, thanks.

**EDIT**

this is what ive tried

```
var app = express();


var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {

    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});

request.post(
    'https://connect.stript.com/oauth/token', {
        form: {
            client_secret: "sk_test_QWnyIomfd2glLk9whe6gOC4f",
            code: "AUTHORIZATION_CODE",
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
        }
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(response)
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)

        }
    }
    );
```

and this is what i get when i skip the account form

```
Cannot GET /?scope=read_write&code=ac_6B0uydoV7XrniZrssm3m2sivUx49cA8M
```

Comment: where are you seeing this error message ?

Comment: so the code you are showing has nothing to do with the error message you are showing right ? from the link https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts#token-request , it says like you need to put a button that opens a new web page with url https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ac_6B0uydoV7XrniZrssm3m2sivUx49cA8M&scope=read_write

Comment: im talking about the part where it says 
`Using the code parameter, you should make a POST request to our access_token_url endpoint`

Comment: have you set any redirect URIs in your platform settings tab ?i mean here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/applications/settings

Answer (score 5):

The reason you get `Cannot GET /?scope=read_write&code=ac_6B0uydoV7XrniZrssm3m2sivUx49cA8M` is that when stripe attempts to redirect to your redirect URI which was set under platform settings, you might have missed to set your redirect URI, also have process when stripe sends the code to your url in the following way

```
app.get('/redirecurlforstripe',function(req,res){
 var params = req.body; // or req.params.query; see which one works for you

  request.post(
    'https://connect.stript.com/oauth/token', {
        form: {
            client_secret: "sk_test_QWnyIomfd2glLk9whe6gOC4f",
            code: params.code, //this will be the authorization code coming from stripe
,
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
        }
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(response)
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)

        }
    }
    );
});
```

Comment: i dont think you understand what im trying to do.

Comment: check my updated answer, let me know if this helps you any way

Answer (score 1):

I set redirectUrl on stripe to http://127.0.0.1:8081/authorize

Here is the code I am using at server side:

```
var CLIENT_ID = 'Your client_id';
var API_KEY = 'Your API_KEY';

var TOKEN_URI = 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token';
var AUTHORIZE_URI = 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize';

var qs = require('querystring');
var request = require('request');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();


app.get('/authorize', function(req, res) {

    var code = req.query.code;

    // Make /oauth/token endpoint POST request
    request.post({
      url: TOKEN_URI,
      form: {
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        code: code,
        client_secret: API_KEY
      }
    }, function(err, r, body) {

      var accessToken = JSON.parse(body).access_token;

      // Do something with your accessToken

      // For demo's sake, output in response:
      res.send({ 'Your Token': accessToken });
      console.log(body);

    });

});

app.listen(8081);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the wrong URL of stripe connect.
'https://connect.stript.com/oauth/token'

you should change this to
'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token'

It worked well on my side.